# (Wordpress / AJAX): Update attachment title, description and alt from frontend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Using wordpress with AJAX I'm trying to update attachment meta from frontend. For some reasons I get json response "**NaN**" or null. This is a form for logged users so I'm not using `wp_ajax_nopriv_`

In my **functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_portfolio', 'update_portfolio_function' );
function update_portfolio_function(){
    $id = $_POST['pid'];
    $title = $_POST['itemtitle'];
    $description = $_POST['itemdescription'];
    $attachment = array(
        'ID' => $id,
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $description
    );
    // now update main post body
    wp_update_post( $attachment );
    die();

    $response = array('pid'=>$id,'title'=>$title);
    echo wp_send_json($response);
    exit;
}
```

And in my jQuery / AJAX I have:

```
function update_info(id, itemtitle, itemdescription)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url : ajaxurl,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'action':'update_portfolio_function',
            'pid' : id,
            'itemtitle' : itemtitle,
            'itemdescription' : itemdescription,
        },
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data.pid + data.title); //Damn
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
      //alert("a");
}
```

As response I want to check if `id` and `title` have been submitted correctly. As you can see I'm using an alert to print them. Values are well passed into the jQuery function but I don't think they're received from my php side (or badly processed) since I get "NaN" as response on `data.pid` and `data.title`. Can you help me?

**EDIT**
My request details

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault. Oversight here:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_portfolio', 'update_portfolio_function' );
```

should be

```
add_action('wp_ajax_update_portfolio_function', 'update_portfolio_function' );
```

Fixed.